# How to format CDROM using Windows 7 from the command prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, compact-disc

I'm currently using Windows 7 to create multiple copies of CDROM using a batch file.  I could automate the copying of files but I'm not able to find out how to format the CDROM from the command prompt.

Currently, I use the following method to create my CDROM:

1. Insert CDCROM. Click on CDROM using Windows explorer.
2. Select "Format disk" when prompted with the message "You need to format the disk in drive E: before you can use it. Do you want to format it?"
3. Windows prompts "How do you want to format your disk?". I enter the disc title, e.g. "My test disc 26 Feb 13" and select "Like a USB flash disk drive".
4. After it has been formatted, i run the following batch file to copy the files over to the CDROM.

   xcopy "D:\CDROM Burning\CDROM 1\" e:\ /e
   pause

My question is, can I automate step 2 to step 3 using the command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this The "Unix Way" using "CDR Tools 4 Windows".

You would use mkisofs (or possibly a Windows equivalent program that can make a ".iso" file from your files)

You would then use cdrecord to burn the iso to the disk.  (No formatting, no XCOPY)